# Can't find instructions to get rid of HTML_TITLE_SUBJ_DIFF

Tags: email, spam, newsletter, email-spam, spamassassin

Outlook 2013 tests my newsletter with a few tests, and gives the newsletter a Spam-Score of 3.9 (5 is required). I wan't to have the score as low as possible, but I can't find what to do at the "HTML_TITLE_SUBJ_DIFF"-Test, and nowhere is written what's that for a test is.

Do you have some experience with that?

Thanks in advance.
Regards, john

Answer (score 2):

After digging configuration and sources of spamassassin-3.3.2:

Length of title in html seems to be 3.5 times longer than length of email subject.

Make html title shorter or email subject longer.

Answer (score 0):

John -

You can always rescore the rule manually. In your local.cf file you can have a line like this:

```
score HTML_TITLE_SUBJ_DIFF 0.0
```

The scores in the local.cf override all scores elsewhere.